# MongoDB generic transaction solution

Tags: mongodb, frameworks, transactions

There is a recommended way to do transactions in mongodb: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Is there a solution/framework out there, which encapsulates all that necessary transaction logic automatically for any insert/update/delete statement?

Comment: Depends on the language. What language are you intending to use?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a solution that makes mongoDB into a fully safe, multi-document, transactional system? I'd recommend you pick a different database that was built with that in mind.

Comment: This has been asked before in a variety of ways: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mongodb+transactions  I'd recommend reading through some of those Q&As.

Comment: MongoDB 4.0+ now supports multi document transactions https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/